# Transformation of django dataset

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

```
class Package (models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Package_feature (models.Model):
    category = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2,
        default=Decimal('0.00'))
    package= models.ForeignKey(Package, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
          null=True)
```

the content of Package is as follows:

```
name
set1
set2
set3
set4
set5
```

the content of Package_feature is as follows:

```
  category         price package
'network equip ',  5000, set1
'network equip ',  4000, set2
'network equip ',  3000, set3
'computer equip',  2000, set1
'computer equip',  1500, set2
'computer equip',  1000, set3
'accessories',      200, set4
'accessories',      300, set1
'accessories',      500, set2
'others',           300, set5
```

What I want to produce is a data structure of the following:

```
  category          set1  set2  set3  set4  set5
'network equip',    5000, 4000, 3000,   -,    -
'computer equip',   2000, 1500, 1000,   -,    -
'accessories',       300,  500,    -, 500,  300
```

Can this be done using django query or i have to hand code the result table?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. Using `distinct()` get the categories first.

Then query the name of packages.

```
categories = Package_feature.objects.values('category').distinct()
packages = Package.objects.values('name')
package_to_pos = { name:pos for pos,name in enumerate(packages) }
no_of_packages = len(package_to_pos)
result = []
for category in categories: 
    pakages_for_cateogory = Package_feature.objects.filter(category = category)
    prices = ['-']*len(no_of_packages)
    for e in pakages_for_cateogory:
        prices[ package_to_pos[e.package.name] ] = e.price
    result.append( (category,prices) )
```